# Why Strategy.entry price and strategy.exit have the same price and appear in the same candle?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have written the following strategy. The result of strategy tester looked good, but the strategy entry price and exit price were the same and appearing in the same candle. When I did the paper trade via 3Commas, the triggered deal closed almost immediately. That implied what I saw on the chart in TradingView was real. Could anyone help check what's wrong with my set up? Thanks in advance.

```
//@version=5
strategy("CEZES - Long Entry Above ZLSMA and EMA50, Short Entry Below", shorttitle="CEZES", overlay=true, initial_capital=1000)
// 10-Sep-2023: Covering 0.1% commission of Binance.
BinanceCommission = 0.001

//===========================================================================
// INDICATORS
//===========================================================================

// Chandelier Exit Indicator
length_ce = input(title='CE ATR Period', defval=1)
mult = input.float(title='CE ATR Multiplier', step=0.1, defval=2.0)
showLabels_ce = input(title='CE Show Buy/Sell Labels ?', defval=true)
useClose_ce = input(title='CE Use Close Price for Extremums ?', defval=true)
highlightState_ce = input(title='CE Highlight State ?', defval=true)

atr_ce = mult * ta.atr(length_ce)

longStop_ce = (useClose_ce ? ta.highest(close, length_ce) : ta.highest(length_ce)) - atr_ce
longStopPrev_ce = nz(longStop_ce[1], longStop_ce)
longStop_ce := close[1] > longStopPrev_ce ? math.max(longStop_ce, longStopPrev_ce) : longStop_ce

shortStop_ce = (useClose_ce ? ta.lowest(close, length_ce) : ta.lowest(length_ce)) + atr_ce
shortStopPrev_ce = nz(shortStop_ce[1], shortStop_ce)
shortStop_ce := close[1] < shortStopPrev_ce ? math.min(shortStop_ce, shortStopPrev_ce) : shortStop_ce

var int dir_ce = 1
dir_ce := close > shortStopPrev_ce ? 1 : close < longStopPrev_ce ? -1 : dir_ce

var color longColor_ce = color.green
var color shortColor_ce = color.red

longStopPlot_ce = plot(dir_ce == 1 ? longStop_ce : na, title='Long Stop', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(longColor_ce, 0))
buySignal_ce = dir_ce == 1 and dir_ce[1] == -1
plotshape(buySignal_ce ? longStop_ce : na, title='Long Stop Start', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(longColor_ce, 0))
plotshape(buySignal_ce and showLabels_ce ? longStop_ce : na, title='Buy Label', text='Buy', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(longColor_ce, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

shortStopPlot_ce = plot(dir_ce == 1 ? na : shortStop_ce, title='Short Stop', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.new(shortColor_ce, 0))
sellSignal_ce = dir_ce == -1 and dir_ce[1] == 1
plotshape(sellSignal_ce ? shortStop_ce : na, title='Short Stop Start', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(shortColor_ce, 0))
plotshape(sellSignal_ce and showLabels_ce ? shortStop_ce : na, title='Sell Label', text='Sell', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(shortColor_ce, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

midPricePlot = plot(ohlc4, title='', style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0, display=display.none, editable=false)

longFillColor = highlightState_ce ? dir_ce == 1 ? longColor_ce : na : na
shortFillColor = highlightState_ce ? dir_ce == -1 ? shortColor_ce : na : na
fill(midPricePlot, longStopPlot_ce, title='Long State Filling', color=longFillColor, transp=90)
fill(midPricePlot, shortStopPlot_ce, title='Short State Filling', color=shortFillColor, transp=90)

changeCond = dir_ce != dir_ce[1]

// ZLSMA - Zero Lag LSMA
length_zlsma = input(title='ZLSMA Length', defval=100)
offset_zlsma = input(title='ZLSMA Offset', defval=0)
src_zlsma = input(close, title='ZLSMA Source')
lsma_zlsma = ta.linreg(src_zlsma, length_zlsma, offset_zlsma)
lsma2_zlsma = ta.linreg(lsma_zlsma, length_zlsma, offset_zlsma)
eq_zlsma = lsma_zlsma - lsma2_zlsma
zlsma_zlsma = lsma_zlsma + eq_zlsma

plot(zlsma_zlsma, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), linewidth=3)

// EMA 50 Indicator
ema50 = ta.ema(close, 50)
plot(ema50, color=color.orange, linewidth=3)
//===========================================================================

// User-defined Risk-to-Reward Ratio Input
risk_to_reward_ratio = input.float(1.5, title="Risk to Reward Ratio")

// Entry and Exit Conditions
var float longStopPrice = na
var float shortStopPrice = na
//var float adjustedLongTakeProfit = na
//var float adjustedShortTakeProfit = na
//var float adjustedLongStopLoss = na
//var float adjustedShortStopLoss = na

longCondition = buySignal_ce and (low > zlsma_zlsma) and (low > ema50)
shortCondition = sellSignal_ce and (high < zlsma_zlsma) and (high < ema50)

LongEntryComment= // hidden
LongExitComment = // hidden
ShortEntryComment = // hidden
ShortExitComment = // hidden

//RecentSwingLow = ta.lowest(low, 15)
//RecentSwingHigh = ta.highest(high, 15)

if (longCondition)
    longStopPrice := zlsma_zlsma
    //strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=longStopPrice, comment = LongEntryComment)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=longStopPrice)

if (shortCondition)
    shortStopPrice := zlsma_zlsma
    //strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=shortStopPrice, comment = ShortEntryComment)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=shortStopPrice)    

// Calculate adjusted take profit and stop loss levels
adjustedLongTakeProfit = open + (open - zlsma_zlsma) * (risk_to_reward_ratio * (1 + BinanceCommission))
adjustedShortTakeProfit = open - (zlsma_zlsma - open) * (risk_to_reward_ratio * (1 + BinanceCommission))

// Calculate adjusted stop loss levels
adjustedLongStopLoss = zlsma_zlsma
adjustedShortStopLoss = zlsma_zlsma

//strategy.exit("Long Stop", from_entry="Long", qty=1, stop=adjustedLongStopLoss, limit=adjustedLongTakeProfit, comment = LongExitComment)
//strategy.exit("Short Stop", from_entry="Short", qty=1, stop=adjustedShortStopLoss, limit=adjustedShortTakeProfit, comment = ShortExitComment)

strategy.exit("Long Stop", from_entry="Long", qty=1, stop=adjustedLongStopLoss, limit=adjustedLongTakeProfit)
strategy.exit("Short Stop", from_entry="Short", qty=1, stop=adjustedShortStopLoss, limit=adjustedShortTakeProfit)


plotshape(longCondition, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.normal, title="Long Entry")
plotshape(shortCondition, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, size=size.normal, title="Short Entry")
```

[Sample candle enclosing the short entry/exit trade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpWnK.png)

[Sample candle enclosing the long entry/exit trade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjTP0.png)

1. I first suspect the exiting deal was of previous trade. So I commented out the long entry and long exit line, and verified the exit trade was of the same entry trade in the same candle.
2. I increased the risk-to-reward ratio, the arrows of stop-loss/take-profit didn't move at all.

Comment: I suggest you take advantage of Pine's new(ish) `log.info()` function and do a Print Driven Development session and print everything into the logs. I suspect either 1., your entry/exit conditionals are both true at the same time, or 2., your SL/TP is set so tight that it immediately triggers. The latter can be made a bit more visible by giving different exit messages to the standard Exits and to SL/TP exits.